# What is a word for someone who likes bossing people around?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I'm looking for a term for someone who get kicks by being bossy, or getting people to do what they demand.

Comment: This question might be better if you included what you found when you looked up _bossy_ in a thesaurus, and elaborated on why some of the better candidates in that list didn't meet your expectations.

Comment: It's a symptom of [assholic behavior](http://geoffreynunberg.com/).

Comment: "Project manager"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *[martinet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/martinet#Noun)* is  “Anyone who lays stress on a rigid adherence to the details of discipline, or to forms and fixed methods or rules”.  It happens to be “a term for someone who get kicks by being bossy, or getting people to do what they demand”.  Also consider  *[despot](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/despot#Noun)*, “A ruler with absolute power; a tyrant”, and
 *[dictator](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dictator#Noun)*, “A totalitarian leader of a country, nation, or government”  or “A tyrannical boss, or authority figure”.  Both words may be figuratively applied.   *[Tyrant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tyrant#Noun)*, “An absolute ruler who governs without restriction” or  “An oppressive, cruel and harsh person” may be slightly less applicable.

Comment: Good suggestions. _Bully_ might be appropriate too for some uses.

Comment: *Martinet* surely is just about perfect.  If you choose *tyrant*, a variant that might "turn the knife" a little is *petty tyrant*, which has a nice added overtone.

Comment: Also, there's *authoritarian*, which somehow doesn't seem to strike the right tone, or *taskmaster*.

Answer (score 3):

My reservation with "martinet" is that the martinet might get kicks out of the conformance to rules and routines, not from being bossy.  Obsessively enforcing discipline is not the same as being bossy.

A bossy person might be **on a power trip**.  Apparently the American Heritage® Dictionary (and thousands of Google results) indicate that **power tripper** is a word, but by ngrams it is several orders of magnitude less common than the former.

My sister's coworker once referred to a colleague as Il Duce, but that's about two steps away from calling somebody Hitler.

**

Regarding the note in the comments below,

I would call her a **sadist** (somebody who gets pleasure from making others unhappy).  Because of gender stereotypes, there are also a bunch of other 'bossy' words for women.  **Harridan** came to mind, which means 'a strict, bossy, or belligerent old woman' and which Google also linked to the synonyms *shrew, virago, harpy, termagant, vixen, nag, hag, crone, dragon, ogress; fishwife, hellcat, she-devil, fury, gorgon, martinet, tartar, spitfire; (informal) old bag, old bat, old trout, old cow, bitch, battleaxe, witch; (rare) scold, Xanthippe*

Of these I think only **battleax** might fit the bill.

Comment: That's interesting - here's the backstory for the word. I was looking for an appropriate word to describe a flight attendant who was overzealous about having a passenger turn off his computer. I mentioned that she seemed to derive pleasure from forcing him to turn off his computer when she asked. What do you think of martinet in this context? And sorry not to provide before!

Comment: @YPCrumble See edits above.

Comment: YPCrumble If you had provided the context many of the suggested answers would have been immediately discarded. I thought you were talking about a company manager or boss. In this case, your expression, over zealous, fits the flight attendant's behaviour quite perfectly

Comment: Its called trying to implement flight regulations with belligerent passengers who think their needs are greater than the safety of all a.k.a. doing her job!

Answer (score 2):

[Bossy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bossy) - *adjective* - fond of giving people orders; domineering

[Synonyms:](http://thesaurus.com/browse/bossy) domineering, pushy, overbearing, imperious, officious, high-handed, authoritarian, dictatorial, controlling, tyrannical, despotic

If you're looking for a noun instead of an adjective, [dictator](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dictator), [despot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/despot) or [tyrant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tyrant) all fit pretty nicely.

Comment: There it is!  I wondered why it took so long to come up with "Bossy", since it fits perfectly.  Even if it is a bit prosaic.  One might want a more intellectual-sounding word, just for grins.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

> I was looking for an appropriate word to describe a flight attendant
>   who was overzealous about having a passenger turn off his computer. I
>   mentioned that she seemed to derive pleasure from forcing him to turn
>   off his computer when she asked.

In this context I would suggest that the flight attendant might be considered;

- ***petty***
- ***mean-spirited*** [*Having a base, nasty, petty, or malevolent disposition.*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mean-spirited)
- ***malicious*** *spiteful and deliberately harmful*

Or, that the attendant ***harassed*** the passenger needlessly.

> A [harassing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harass) flight
>   attendant took pleasure in exerting her authority.

.

---

**Taskmaster** *One who imposes tasks, especially burdensome or laborious ones and a person, discipline, etc., that enforces work, esp hard or continuous work.*

From *Great Expectations*, Charles Dickens

> A better proof of the severity of my bondage to that taskmaster could
>   scarcely be afforded, than the degrading shifts to which I was
>   constantly driven to find him employment.

By the same author; *A Christmas Carol*

> pitiless taskmaster that he was, Ebenezer Scrooge only reluctantly let
>   his ill-paid clerk have Christmas Day off