# What else can you call someone who is rhetorically bombastic?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions, pejorative-language, offensive-language

For example when someone exclaims, *"What the heck are you talking about"*, if you were mildly incorrect on any matter or simply stating something in a general dialogue. Typically the person will assert things like, **"Obviously"**, ***"Of course"***, or *"Everyone knows that"* – these being obnoxious and vociferous rhetorical exclamations can also often be followed by a quick and faint, *"Come on"*. The previous said quotes being said on **many** occasions in simple mindful discourses rather than arguments or disputes.

**So exactly what is an alternative name or synonym that you can label a person who is rhetorically bombastic?**

The labels that are convenient and fitting for this request currently is: *browbeat*, *castigate*, and *condescending*!

**Edited to add information from comment**:

I'm looking for a noun.

Comment: I'm not sure where the "rhetorically bombastic" bit figures here. Are you talking about someone who's rudely dismissive of what others say or think?

Comment: Not necessarily dismissive towards others' statements or thoughts, but **definitely** rude and can usually be equipped with some sort of a condescending yet vehement tone in their responses regardless of whether or not it's a simple conversation or a dispute.

Comment: Well, I'd say every italicised example in your question is primarily ***dismissive / condescending*** - but there aren't many contexts where they wouldn't inevitably be blatantly rude as well.

Comment: I'm just looking for some kind of _specific_ label—preferably a noun—rather than a simple adjective for this type of person that's all.

Comment: Could it be *browbeating*?

Comment: That's actually quite a **profound** one, and that'd suffice with the exception of the "intimidation" in my case. If anyone else could procure a similar term - my day would be made!

Comment: I see the problem as the speaker's *hollowness*.

Comment: %$@# loudmouth know-it-all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) The type of speech you describe could be called **bluster** and a person who blusters is called a ***blusterer***

> bluster 1. **Talk in a loud, aggressive, or indignant way** with little effect.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bluster
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blusterer

Example:

> (...) at least this bullying ***blusterer*** of a politician was prepared to take action (...)

[Pl. click on the 'example' button in the above linked page to read the full sentence and more instances of its use]

(2) An idiomatic expression that suits your description would be **cock of the walk**

> **cock of the walk** [noun] : the leader in a group, especially one with a conceited, domineering manner.

[Definition of 'cock of the walk' at Collins dictionary online](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cock-of-the-walk)

(3) You should consider adjectives as well, because the vast majority of the appropriate choices for your question are descriptive words rather than nouns, and one descriptor that fits your case well is **overbearing**.

> overbearing
>
> 1a: tending to overwhelm : overpowering
>
> 2 :  harshly and haughtily arrogant
>
> *the mayor's overbearing manner of dealing with employees*

[Definition of overbearing at Merriam-Webster online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overbearing)

Moreover simply googling 'overbearing' opens up a large number and variety of terms that are close in meaning:

> (...) overbearing : unpleasantly overpowering.
> *"an overbearing, ill-tempered brute"*
> **synonyms**: domineering, dominating, autocratic, tyrannical, despotic, heavy-handed, oppressive, high-handed, bullying, high and mighty, lordly, lording it, officious, masterful, dictatorial, bossy, imperious, pontifical, pompous, peremptory, arrogant, cocksure, proud, overproud, overweening, presumptuous, opinionated, dogmatic; More
> informal: pushy, throwing one's weight about, cocky

See [Definition and synonyms of overbearing by Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=overbearing&oq=overbearing&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.4193j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#xxri=1)

(4) **In terms of a specific label**, you could sarcastically call an overbearing person a **despot / tyrant / dictator**, where the tyranny lies in dismissing the ideas and opinions of others. I have read of such types described as a ***great dictator*** or a ***little dictator***.

> My mother-in-law is *such* a dictator.
>
> Back to your desks, look right industrious and don't talk back -- the great dictator is just stepping out of his cabin!
>
> It can be fairly trying to work with this little dictator.

In India I have heard such a person sarcastically called *a Hitler* (as in *'be cautious while working with so-and-so; he is a Hitler!'*) but I understand any reference to Hitler would be highly controversial in Europe and maybe also in the USA. Other possible labels are **little king**, **little prince**, and **little lord** which can be likewise deployed sarcastically to refer to the person's overbearing behavior.

> He ran the office *like a little king* and earned the ire of his staff members.
>
> "I been tryin' to do this job the best I can, but I got my work cut out; and *the little prince* with his bossy ways ain't makin' it any easier, for sure!"
>
> "*The little lord* has no sense, but brooks no argument -- just talking to him gives me a headache -- this business is going to sink within the year."

You might get some more ideas by reading the comments and answers to this closely related question asked earlier at this same website:

[What is a word for someone who likes bossing people around?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133876/what-is-a-word-for-someone-who-likes-bossing-people-around)

Answer (score 0):

This person is a

***know-it-all***

> a person who acts as though he or she knows everything and who dismisses the opinions, comments, or suggestions of others.

*([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/know--it--all?s=t))*

Answer (score 0):

This kind of dictator is usually called a tinpot dictator to indicate the expanse of his realm.

Sounds like a plain old "Jerk" [reference needed] to me. He needs a civil tongue and some listening lessons.

Can you share with us who will get your description using this new noun?