# what is a word for a person who is scornful?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for one word that can be used instead of "scornful person". The only word I can think of is "superior" as a noun.

---

Edit from comments:

I can find tons of adjectives with no noun forms. I guess I am looking for a word that is a little more dramatic, more insulting [than *scorner*].

Comment: See *condescending* and all its synonyms of which the only noun I could locate is 'snob' --
Why dont all these adjectives have noun forms! Here is the link: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=condecending+synonyms&oq=condecending+synonyms&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.9524j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Will scorner work for you?  If not, please let us know why not?  A little more context would be helpful.

Comment: agreed that i can find tons of adjectives with no noun forms. i suppose scorner would work - i guess i am looking for a word that is a little more dramatic, more insulting

Comment: Do you like **killjoy** --  something similar in meaning... see this definition and synonyms: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=killjoy&oq=killjoy&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.5678j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Also see this rather similar recent Q https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391366/what-else-can-you-call-someone-who-is-rhetorically-bombastic

Comment: Could you add a sentence showing how you would like to use the word? That would give us a better sense of exactly what kind of word you want, and it's technically required for single-word-requests. Also, I'm going to edit in the background you've mentioned in your comment. Feel free to change or add to this when you add the example sentence—the more information we have, for example about the kinds of words you've already looked at and why they don't work for you, the better our answers are likely to be. Good luck!

Comment: Its yiddish but you could use "farbissiner"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**cynic**

> meaning "sneering sarcastic person" is from 1590s.

Also:

- **misanthrope** *hater of humankind* (but from my observation can mean a general hatred, or distrust, or contempt)
- More common than **misanthrope** in common speech today is **hater** (which from my observation can mean someone who is scornful in general or about a specific thing, like "don't be such a *hater* about the President.")
- Another slang word is **ass** (which from my observation can be used pretty broadly, to include a scornful person.)
- **naysayer** is *a person who habitually expresses negative or pessimistic views*

All definitions above from www.dictionary.com

Edit:  @oskmatz suggested I add the following additional  word to the list above, and I agree it is a useful addition:

- **shrew** is a gendered term for a persistently critical woman, often a wife: "a bad-tempered or aggressively assertive woman."

Comment: @oskmatz thanks for your idea to add *shrew* to the list above and for your definition you provided - I have added both to the list above!

Comment: Scold works, too, as long as directed towards not me.

Comment: I'm not seeing how Shrew works here. There is nothing in the definition that requires expressing scorn. Scorn isn't just criticism.

Comment: @Spagirl I think there are overlaps. Dictionary.com says *The meaning "peevish, malignant, clamorous, spiteful, vexatious, turbulent woman" [Johnson] is late 14c., from earlier sense of "spiteful person" (male or female), mid-13c.*  I think there are overlaps between *scornful* and meanings like *malignant, spiteful,* etc.  It can be considered *scornful* behavior that also tends to be angry and/or vindictive.

Comment: Well, for one - usage from the 14c is of limited application to a modern situations. For two,Dictionary.com's contemporary definition speaks only of violent temper or speech, neither of which is a necessary part of scorn, nor vice versa.

Comment: @Spagirl  Your comments are inaccurate.  Dictionary.com gives multiple sources.  Your quotation is based on Random House Dictionary, whereas mine is based on  Douglas Harper's Online Etymology Dictionary.  Both are contemporary.  My definition is the meaning since the 14c, so not *of limited application in modern situations* as you claim.  Also cited is from Collins English Dictionary which states "a bad-tempered or mean-spirited woman" with *mean spirited* the same as *malignant, spiteful,* etc. that I previously noted so again contemporary.

Comment: @Spagirl to further underscore my point I believe very few people think of the word *shrew* today without also thinking of Shakespeare's *Taming of the Shrew* and that's a play about a woman who is *scornful* and disobedient.  From the play:  "*unknit that threat'ning unkind brow / And dart not scornful glances from those eyes / To wound thy lord*."  From a review in the San Diego Reader:  "*For as much as Bianca charms and obeys, Katherina, also known as Kate, scorns and disobeys*."  If for no other reason than Shakespeare's fame, there's a clear connection between *shrew* and *scorn*.