# What is a word for someone who abuses their workers?

Tags: synonyms

I have been trying to find a word to describe someone who routinely abuses their workers, and perhaps even more than that, scorns them and sees them as inferior. My first guess was *despot* but I think that is more routinely used within the context of political leaders.

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I don't think that there is a good single word that expresses the concept well, but if two words are fine for you "abusive manager" or "abusive boss" is clear enough.

Comment: "Tyrant" would also come under the heading of bad boss/bad political leader

Comment: "Workplace bully" might work.

Comment: Informally, "Asshole" (UK: "Arsehole").

Comment: A Marxist would say "a capitalist".

Comment: ... and someone on the other side of the spectrum  might make reference to the "gulag commander", or to Stalin. (Beria would probably be beyond the pale, even in this context).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A *slave driver* (informal)

> someone who makes another person work very hard with little or no help or remuneration.

([Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/slave-driver))

Comment: No, I don't think this should be the accepted answer.  This is different from what was asked.  The workers could easily be abused and scorned, and yet adequately paid or even well-paid. I think the question was asking about how they were treated, apart from remuneration.  Erwin Bolwidt's comment answer of "abusive manager" or "abusive boss" is much better, in my opinion.

Comment: @JeffRoe: "Slavedriver" can still be used metaphorically to mean a harsh taskmaster, even if the workers are ultimately paid well.

Answer (score 12):

You could use

> **taskmaster** [noun]
>
> a person who imposes a harsh or onerous workload on someone.
>
> - "he was a hard taskmaster"

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/taskmaster)]

There is a related question here, [What is a word for someone who likes bossing people around?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133876/what-is-a-word-for-someone-who-likes-bossing-people-around/133882#133882), where you will find martinet / despot / tyrant / harridan / battleax ... more scathing, but these aren't largely confined to the corporate arena.

Comment: I suggest a "hard taskmaster" is about rigidity and strictness, not abuse or unfairness.

Comment: I don't think 'harsh' stops there.

Comment: Edwin, I don't understand. Are you saying "Taskmaster" is not meant to be a neutral term, very like the "gangmaster" many of us might be surprised to note still has clear and useful meaning in modern British labour law? I'm suggesting that in and of itself, "taskmaster" is no worse - nor better - than "foreman" or "overseer" or "supervisor".

Comment: I'm accepting that usage boards at reputable dictionaries are almost always more reliable than individuals. Words have ranges of senses. Note the 'or'.

Comment: Which "or", Edwin? Is that the "or" in "harsh or onerous…" or what?

Comment: I say no adjective. Taskmaster isn't a job title -- it's a replacement to imply bossiness: "I'll try to make it if the taskmaster lets me" is making fun of your boss (or spouse). Of course it can have adjectives, but so can anything.

Comment: I would agree that "taskmaster" is a negative description of a persons behaviour, although it might be a reasonable job title or legal term.  Likewise gangmaster and overseer are probably not positive as they have hints at modern and historical slavery.  The general use in english is that workers who are slaves were treated poorly and that supervisors who treat people poorly have their description given in a way that draws comparison. foreman and supervisor I think are the only neutral ones mentioned.

Comment: @TafT  OP asks for 'a word to describe someone who routinely abuses their workers'. Dictionaries provide definitions, which either fit or don't (though words do have different senses).

Answer (score 5):

Suitable candidates might be "user" or "exploiter" or even simply "abuser."

Others include "bully" and "dictator" as well as "martinet" and "little Napoleon."

I suggest there is no recognised single word, nor phrase for what you've described so far.

Can you say in much more detail how the workers are being abused, and for what reason?

Answer (score -2):

Another term (though probably not as well understood in a politically correct era, is: "Simon Legree."

> [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Simon-Legree)
>
> …the brutal Simon Legree, Tom’s new owner, has Tom whipped to death after he refuses to divulge the whereabouts of certain escaped slaves.
> From *Uncle Tom’s Cabin*

**Simon Legree** (n.)

> A tyrannical, brutal slave-owner. Later usually in weakened use: **an
> exacting, merciless taskmaster**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/simon_legree), OED
>
> 2005   *N.Y. Times* (National ed.) 5 June iii. 10/4   *I had one boss
> early in my career who was very bright but would lose his temper... My
> job was to be the buffer between that **Simon Legree** and the rest of
> the troops.* (OED)

> Any cruel taskmaster. Webster's New World Dictionary, Third ed.

> A brutal taskmaster. [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=simon%20legree)

---

> American trade-unions are rendering a useful service to freedom in their campaign of telling European trade-unions the trust about Soviet Working conditions. As an additional service, it is suggested that American unions
> distribute translations, without comment, of Russia's incredibly cruel
> labor laws, with her **Simon Legree** penalties for petty infractions.
> "The dictatorship of the proletariat" is the dictatorship over the
> proletariat. [Peter Viereck; *Shame and Glory of the
> Intellectuals*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Making_National_News/TkKWAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22A%20simon%20legree%22&pg=PA90&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

> The reason the staff feels – quite rightly – I am a **Simon Legree** is
> first, because the opposition when I came down here was such that **I
> had to be hard** to get anywhere with an eastern staff annoyed at the
> idea of a westerner coming in; second, because ... [J.F.B. Livesay in
> Gene Allen; *Making National News*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Making_National_News/TkKWAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22A%20simon%20legree%22&pg=PA90&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> “You've Got the Word” No one likes to be **Simon Legree**, but all I
> could say is: “You've got the word now. [Todd Ream; *Hesburgh of Notre
> Dame*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hesburgh_of_Notre_Dame/J4E6EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20be%20simon%20legree%22&pg=PA263&printsec=frontcover) (2021)

> *Uncle Tom's Cabin* gave U.S. culture a series of characters—some would say stereotypes—that became household names over the following century: ... **Simon Legree**, the slavetrader whose very name became a **virtual
> synonym for calculating, heartless evil**; ... [Jim Cullen; *The Art of
> Democracy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Art_of_Democracy/FUWhBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22simon%20legree%22%20tough%20on&pg=PT82&printsec=frontcover) (2002)

> Then when we got it down to 3.8 percent or 3.7 percent, I went in to
> report to **this arm twister, this taskmaster, this Simon Legree**,
> and his answer was, “3.7 percent where?” And we said, “In the
> country." [*Proceedings of the Constitutional Convention of the
> AFL-CIO*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Proceedings_of_the_Constitutional_Conven/9cREAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22this%20simon%20legree%22&dq=%22this%20simon%20legree%22&printsec=frontcover) (1967)

Comment: Or, for that matter, "Scrooge".

Comment: Can you give more details to this suggestion? Explain why is 'Simon Legree' is relevant here.

Comment: Simon Legree was the rather bad overseer in "Uncle Tom's Cabin."

Comment: A Simon Legree is "an exacting, merciless taskmaster" [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/simon_legree) and OED. Why was it downvoted?

Comment: @DnjinTonic Making a guess, but I'd never heard of this before; I assume it's regional or maybe a part of the AAVE dialect? Not many people read Uncle Tom's Cabin nowadays...

Comment: @DjinTonic Uncle Tom’s Cabin was very much disliked in the South. It is tempting to think that the downvoters, none of whom have explained their vote to us, are continuing that inhumane tradition even to the present day.

Comment: @nick012000 That may be true, but lesser-known words/terms are often offered as (possible) answers on ELU. IMO a downvote should be reserved for an answer that the voter judges to be wrong or that contains incorrect information. I agree that ttw should have offered a definition with their answer, which fits the question to a T.  It's not marked as regional or even *U.S.* in the definitions I've seen.